# Laravel route() url is not showing correct locale url

Tags: laravel

I'm using latest laravel and i'm having my friendly url's in language files (as the website is using 2 languages and I and want each language have different friendly urls).
Therefore we have 2 languages files:
`langs/language1/main.php` and `langs/language2/main.php`.

Each file contain a friendly url, for example:
`return ['url1' => 'url-in-language1'];` & `return ['url1' => 'url-in-language2'];`

Before using route, i'm using `App::setLocale('language2')`;
Then when I'm using `route('url1', ['language' => 'language2'])` in a blade to output the link for language 2, the route is still displayed for language1.

Any idea why this ain't working ? Maybe after `App:setLocale()` i need somehow reload language files ?

Comment: Have you checked after reloading language is changed or not?

Comment: Would you please share the more code or explain this why both have same url as you're trying to route for different urls right?

`Each file contain a friendly url, for example: return ['url1' => 'url-in-language1']; & return ['url1' => 'url-in-language2'];`

Comment: @KamranAllana yes if I use only trans('url1') it shows the correct value.

Comment: Yes, `trans` is used to translate. `setLocale` set the language for translation so would you please share example or brief so I try to help you out.